# app.config and Entity Framework for remote connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I have a connection string to a local database which works ok.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="Entities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/RNADataModel.csdl|
                    res://*/RNADataModel.ssdl|
                    res://*/RNADataModel.msl;
                    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                    provider connection string=&quot;
                    Data Source=my-localhost;
                    Initial Catalog=my-db-name;
                    Integrated Security=True;                        
                    multipleactiveresultsets=True;
                    App=EntityFramework&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

However I cannot figure how to connect to a remote database succesfully. 
I have tried to add `User ID=user`; `Password=pass;` and also disabled `Integrated Security` but the server fails to connect.

Is there a way to fix the connection string or some other workaround to connect to the remote database?

**EDIT**:
The error comes from my web app every time the connection string is not correctly specified:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
```

and

`System.Data.EntityException` throws: `{"The underlying provider failed on Open."}`

If I use SQL Server management studio I can see the database on the server and credentials works fine. Might be some firewall configuration, any suggestions?

Comment: Well what error do you get when connecting to the database?

Comment: Have you setup the DB to accept remote connections? i.e., adding the DB port as an exception to the firewall, enabling TCP connections, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to access the customer's server, so following this guide http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx
I have enabled the remote connection. The Connection string was fine. Thanks the comments

Answer (score 0):

You  need to change Data Source=my-localhost to
Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName
Don't forget to specify the correct UserName & Password